# Adding Image to a Button in Windows 10 Phone App

Tags: windows-phone

I am trying to add an image to a button . I want to archive something like this

[image]

This is what I was trying to do but the image doesn't appear

```
<StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
   <Button x:Name = "kap2"
        FontFamily = "Arial"
        Content = "Te drejtat dhe lirite themelore"
        Width = "250"
        Height = "50"
            HorizontalAllignment = "Left">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource = "Asses/number/1.png" Stretch="Fill">
            </ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word 'Asses' I think it should be 'Assets'.
If this doesn't work, try also

> /Assets/number/1.png

The problem is about spelling. Make sure that folder names are correct and the image name is correct too.